# StartNew() with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke blocks

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Given this code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        //UI Code 1            
    });
    //Non UI Code
    taskResult = SomeMethod();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        //UI Code 2
        if (taskResult)...
    });
});
```

Is `UI Code 2` executed after the `Non UI Code` is finished with execution or does it execute while `Non UI Code` is still running?

In other words, is it safe to assume that taskResult variable will always have the results of Non-UI thread processing when called within `UI Code 2` block?

Comment: You can not assume StartNew will not be on the UI thread unless you pass a scheduler in, see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good one, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given MSDN description for `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

> Executes the specified delegate **synchronously** on the thread the
>   Dispatcher is associated with.

The answer to your question is **Yes**.